# How can I achieve these sci-fi effects from Blade Runner 2049's UI design?

Tags: interface-design, texture

I'm trying to wrap my head around the UI design in Blade Runner 2049. A couple articles just came out talking about Territory Studio's work on the film and their stuff is incredible. I know all the text/lines/etc. are made in Illustrator, but what they do in terms of effects over the top of it looks fantastic. Lots of layered textures that are really hazy, worn-out with screen burn, color fade, whatever else. It looks like there's a subtle inner glow on a lot of but I can't figure out how they made the rest of it look so beat up yet futuristic. You can't just slap some generic grungy textures on the UI because that's not going to look right on what's supposed to be computer screen.

Any guesses as to a few things going on in these images? I'd like to try making some of my own.

[image: Blade Runner 2049 1]

[image: Blade Runner 2049 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from general grain effects, and the "negative" vignette (brightening) effect around the corners, you would want to do some very specific colour filtering around certain areas. The cards have a greenish tint to them but the photos look much colder and more blueish. These are things you can eyedrop in Photoshop and get a better idea of the colouring to replicate.

There are lots of dark areas, in general lots of variation of the levels in the image. That's kind of the key of it, making sure it doesn't look 'flat' brightness wide. There are also 'scratches' on the photo, which you can do mostly with a brush that has a high-brightness mask on it. Texturing is also pretty important in this image, every part of it seems to have a rough texture specifically masked to it. Overall, Getting this right would take a bit of time and care, working with several layers, and working different parts of the image separately, to make sure it all comes together and doesn't look cheap or fake. Hope this helps.